# Reminders (remindd) waste CPU resources 100% / 200%, and obviously drain batteries of my MacBook Pro, Apple Watch (guess) and iPhone (guess)

Tags: macos, reminders

A couple of months ago I decided to get a new MacBook Pro, it felt like the battery on the old one was dying, same applies to my old iPhone. And here I am, with a new MacBook (Intel, i9), new iPhone and Apple Watch. The laptop dies within 1-2 hours without external power. The Apple Watch dies within 5 hours. And the fresh iPhone dies within 12 hours.

After a little bit of checking, I realised that something weird is going on with Reminders. On the laptop, it is `remindd` process that constantly consumes 200% / two cores of CPU. By the moment, I have been too lazy to find a way to check what is going on with the iPhone and Watch, but I suppose it is the same issue, `remindd`. I would have assumed the implementation of the service should be the same, or very similar across all the devices. Including bugs.

I am not taking the ultimately hopeless path of reporting that to Apple, but instead, I am just trying to get rid of all the reminders, everywhere. Which seems to be impossible. Even after creating a little shortcut (Shortcuts app on iOS) and deleting all of them, notifications still appear.

So how can I remove them all?

Comment: @nohillside I am not sure why the answer has been deleted?

Comment: Please post answers in the answer box below, don‘t include it into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Big Sur and have had the same problem for months. Finally decided to reboot reminders the hard way.

1. Disable reminders in **Settings** > **Accounts** > **iCloud**
2. Use Activity Monitor to force quit `remindd`
3. Quit the Reminders application if you have it open.
4. Use Terminal to `rm -rf ~/Library/Reminders`
5. Use Activity Monitor to force quit `remindd` again, just in case.
6. Re-enable reminders in **Settings** > **Accounts** > **iCloud**
7. Watch CPU spike up again for a while...

So none of that worked. The `remindd` process came back and continued churning a sqlite database in the `~/Library/Reminders/` folder to over 300MB in size.

Ultimately, I deleted all the reminders on my iPhone, iPad, and mac. I transferred them into a different list manager. Then I deleted the app from those devices, turned off iCloud syncing for reminders, quit the reminders app on my iMac, et voila, the `remindd` process on my iMac self-terminated and stopped eating my CPU.

I now wonder if this was part of the background battery drain on my iPhone.